# How to inject configuration settings in test classes (ASP.NET Core)?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, dependency-injection, smtp

SmtpConfig contains my credentials which I want to use in a test class.
appsettings.development.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },
  "SmtpConfig": {
    "credentials": "username:password"
  }
}
```

Here I configure the smtpConfig to be injected in classes (in controller classes works very fine!)
Startup.cs

```
public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
      services.AddMvc();

      services.Configure<SmtpConfig(
         Configuration.GetSection(nameof(SmtpConfig)
      ));
}
```

I want to access credentials from appsettings.development.json in tests, because on another server I will have another config file.

```
//important usings
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

[TestClass]
    public class SomeControllerAPITest
    {
       private SmtpConfig _smtpConfig;

        public SomeControllerAPITest(IOptions<SmtpConfig> smtpConfig)
        {
            _smtpConfig = smtpConfig.Value;
        }


        [TestMethod]
        public void Post_ReturnsCreatedInstance()
        {
            var credentials = _smtpConfig.credentials;

            //use that credentials
            ...

            //call remote server
            ...
        }
}
```

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 2):

### - Create class file into testProject

```
public static IConfiguration getConfig(){ 
   var config = new ConfigurationBuilder() 
     .SetBasePath("/Users/Project/")
     .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")  
     .Build(); 
   return config; 
}
```

---

```
    [TestClass]
    public class TestMasterClass
    {
        public static IConfiguration _configuration { get; set; }

        public TestMasterClass()
        {
            _configuration = AnotherClassFile.getConfig();
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestConfigElasticSearch()
        {

            var elasticSearch = _configuration["ElasticSearchConfig:Link01"];
            Assert.IsNotNull(elasticSearch);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This answer could be improved with an explanation of what your code is doing to solve the question asked.

Comment: In the above case Appsettings should be present in Test project right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` binding functionality to build an identically populated `IOptions<TConfiguration>` instance. Here is a rough equivalent of how we implemented this for our test code:

```
public class TestSmtpConfigOptions : IOptions<SmtpConfig> {

    private static Lazy<SmtpConfig> configuration { get; }

    static TestSmtpConfigOptions() {
        configuration = new Lazy<SmtpConfig>(GetConfiguration);
    }

    public SmtpConfig Value {
        get { return configuration.Value; }
    }

    private static SmtpConfig GetConfiguration() {
        var configuration = new SmtpConfig();
        var path = Path.Combine("config", "appsettings.development.json");

        new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath("path/to/base/directory/of/project")
            .AddJsonFile(path, optional: true)
            .Build()
            .GetSection(nameof(SmtpConfig))
            .Bind(configuration);

        return configuration;
    }

}
```

Then, in your fixture, you only need to instantiate it:

```
[TestClass]
public class SomeControllerAPITest {

    private SmtpConfig _smtpConfig;

    public SomeControllerAPITest() {
        _smtpConfig = new TestSmtpConfigOptions().Value;
    }


    [TestMethod]
    public void Post_ReturnsCreatedInstance() {
        var credentials = _smtpConfig.credentials;

        //use that credentials
        ...

        //call remote server
        ...
    }
}
```

In case you care about cross platform paths and don't mind a little extra complexity, here's a little class we use to get the base path in a cross-platform way for our xUnit test runner. This means we use `TestConfiguration.BasePath` instead of `"path/to/base/directory/of/project"` in the example above.

```
internal static class TestConfiguration {

    internal static string BasePath { get; }

    static TestConfiguration() {
        BasePath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BASE_DIRECTORY");

        if (BasePath == null) {
            BasePath = AppContext.BaseDirectory;

            // cross-platform equivalent of "../../../../../"
            for (var index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
                BasePath = Directory.GetParent(BasePath).FullName;
            }
        }
    }

    internal static string ResolvePath(string relativePath) {
        return Path.Combine(BasePath, relativePath);
    }

}
```